# Div fill remaining height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `div`s, the one on the `bottom` has content that expands the highest. The page is 100% height/width `position absolute`

```
<style>
    body, html { height:100%, width:100% }
    .page { position: absolute; height: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0}
    .bottom { position absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; }
    .top { position absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; }
</style>
```

How can i make it so the top `div` convers whatever page the bottom `div` is left, so if the `window` is `600` height, bottom takes `400`, top takes `200`

Comment: Nope but I'm using angular and I was having problems using outerheight

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure CSS is there any reason to have a top div?

**[Check This JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsxtp3j6/2/)**

In this demo you can see that without a top div, you can stick a div in bottom and the parent div fill the remain space.

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
    this is top
    <div class="bottom">
        This is a text
        <br/>
        In order to expand the bottom
        <br />
        blah blah
        <br />
        blah blah blah
        <br />
        blah blah blah blah
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html { height:100%, width:100% }
.page { position: absolute; height: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; background-color:green}
.bottom { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; background-color:red}
```

**Update:**

But if you have to create a top div that fill remain height, it think there is no a cross-browsing solution using pure CSS but you can user a simple JQuery code.

Assume you have this HTML:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="top">
        this is top
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        This is a text
        <br/>
        In order to expand the bottom
        <br />
        blah blah
        <br />
        blah blah blah
        <br />
        blah blah blah blah
    </div>
</div>
```

So use this JS:

```
function setHeight() {
    $(".top").height($(".page").height() - $(".bottom").height());
}

$(document).ready(setHeight);
$(window).resize(setHeight);
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsxtp3j6/3/)**

Comment: The top has a image with is expanded 1005

Comment: @user3105560: you say "so if the window is 600 height, bottom takes 400, top takes 200" what happen for this image in this case? do you really need the top div? what happen if you put this image in page div? (insted of `this is top` in html code).

Comment: the image property is 100% height and the bottom div overlaps it instead of the image being max-height:100% and taking the 200

Comment: @user3105560: I figure out your case, check the updated answer and let me know the result.